# change background color of containing html element of radio button select

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I've this...

```
<ul class="article-types">
<li class="article-option">
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="first" value="option1">
        Lorem
    </label>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</li>
<li class="article-option">
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="second" value="option2">
        Ipsum
    </label>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</li>
```

What I want is just changing the .article-option to .highlight when radio button is checked. Notice there are two radio buttons (can be even more), if the selected radio is unchecked, the class .highlight must gone. Two **li** can never have .highlight at the same time. Either one depending on the radiobutton status.

How can I do this with jQuery? jsFiddle can be good.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, what have you tried? This is not a _gimme the code_ website.

Comment: + you said "jsFiddle can be good", what about providing one people can fork?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go through all of your radiobuttons and check for `:checked`
Check that out: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BLYp3/1/)

Comment: thanks you. simply worked.

Answer (score 1):

Look at jQuery's [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) method.

```
$("input[name=optionsRadios]").on("change", function(event) { /* DO WORK */ });
```

You could also use the [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) method, however, through time and experience I've found many situations where .change just simply produces better results.

Also, Look at jQuery's `:checked` selector. [jQuery :checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

```
if ($("input[name=optionsRadios]").is(":checked");) { /* DO WORK */ }
```

See this old jsFiddle I made to answer another SO question. They show a few differences about change and even click on a checkbox in one of them.

- [jQuery Checkbox Workings](http://fiddle.jshell.net/SpYk3/Z2NN7/)
- [Understanding Checkbox Toggle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/SpYk3/JKdsH/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[type=radio]').click(function(){
    $('.article-types li').attr('class' , 'article-option');
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
        $(this).parent().parent().addClass('highlight').removeClass('article-option');
    else
        $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('highlight').addClass('article-option');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type=radio]').click(function(){
      //this will reverse the previous clicked radio class
      $(".highlight").addClass("article-option").removeClass("highlight"); 
      $(this).closest('li').find(".article-option").addClass("highlight").removeClass("article-option");

   });
});
```

Use the above code this will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

with jquery u can use parent function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type='radio']").each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            $("input[type='radio']").is(":not(':checked')").each(function(){
                //in css set colour
                $("this").parent().css();
            }
            $("input[type='radio']").is(":checked").each(function(){
                //in css set colour
                $("this").parent().css();
            }

        });
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Demo is here http://jsfiddle.net/2dJAN/30/

```
  $(".radio").click(function(){
    $( ".article-option" ).removeClass('highlight')
    if($(".radio").is(':checked')){
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('highlight')
        }
});


.highlight {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#ddd;
    padding:4px 11px;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:16px;
}
```